# unable to discover BLE devices

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have 2 android phones. I found that both support BLE from the code below. But the phones are unable to search each other. Do I have to put extra code in other mobile also? Currently, I am running the code from 1 mobile and switching on Bluetooth icon on the other phone.

From OnCreate, I am using runtime permission for bluetooth. Then calling scanBLE() method. In that ble is scaned. 1 Adapter is extended from base adapter and named LeDeviceListAdapter.

CODE:
AndroidManifest.xml:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
        <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" android:required="false"/>
```

BTScanActivity.java:

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public class BTScanActivity extends ListActivity {
    private BluetoothLeScanner bluetoothLeScanner;
    private Handler handler;
    private boolean mScanning;
    private LeDeviceListAdapter mLeDeviceListAdapter;
    int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
    BluetoothManager bluetoothManager;
    BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;
    static final int REQUEST = 112;
    // Stops scanning after 10 seconds.
    private static final long SCAN_PERIOD = 10000;

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_b_t_scan);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            String[] PERMISSIONS = {Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION};
            if (!hasPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS)) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) this, PERMISSIONS, REQUEST );
                //imagePath.setText("SDK>23,has no permission");
                Toast.makeText(this, "SDK greater than 23,has no permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                scanLe();

            } else {
                //do here
                //imagePath.setText("SDK>23,has no permission");
                Toast.makeText(this, "SDK lesser than 23,has no permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                scanLe();

            }
        } else {
            //do here
            //imagePath.setText("SDK<23");
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "The app was  allowed to read your store.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                scanLe();
            }

        }

    }
    private static boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String... permissions) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && context != null && permissions != null) {
            for (String permission : permissions) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    //do here
                    Toast.makeText(this, "The app was  allowed to read your store.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "The app was not allowed to read your store.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private void scanLe()
    {
        if (!getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "ble_not_supported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "ble_supported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                bluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
                bluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();
                if (bluetoothAdapter == null || !bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                    Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                    startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
                }
                //bluetoothLeScanner = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getBluetoothLeScanner();
                handler = new Handler();
                mLeDeviceListAdapter = new LeDeviceListAdapter(this);
                setListAdapter(mLeDeviceListAdapter);
                scanLeDevice(true);
            }
        }
    }
    private void scanLeDevice(final boolean enable) {
        if (enable) {
            // Stops scanning after a pre-defined scan period.
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mScanning = false;
                    bluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
                    //invalidateOptionsMenu();
                }
            }, SCAN_PERIOD);
            mScanning = true;
            bluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
        } else {
            mScanning = false;
            bluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
        }
        //invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }
    // Device scan callback.
    private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback =
            new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, int rssi, byte[] scanRecord) {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            //Toast.makeText(this, "adding device", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            mLeDeviceListAdapter.addDevice(device);
                            mLeDeviceListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    });
                }
            };
    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView deviceName;
        TextView deviceAddress;
        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            deviceName = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.device_name);
            deviceAddress = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.device_address);
        }
    }
    // Adapter for holding devices found through scanning.
    private class LeDeviceListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> mLeDevices;
        //private LayoutInflater mInflator;
        private Context context;
        public LeDeviceListAdapter(Context context/*, ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> items*/) {
            super();
            this.mLeDevices = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();
            this.context = context;
            //mInflator = BTScanActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();
        }
        public void addDevice(BluetoothDevice device) {
            if(!mLeDevices.contains(device)) {
                mLeDevices.add(device);
            }
        }
        public BluetoothDevice getDevice(int position) {
            return mLeDevices.get(position);
        }
        public void clear() {
            mLeDevices.clear();
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mLeDevices.size();
        }
        @Override
        public Object getItem(int i) {
            return mLeDevices.get(i);
        }
        @Override
        public long getItemId(int i) {
            return i;
        }
        @Override
        public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            ViewHolder viewHolder;
            // General ListView optimization code.
            if (view == null) {
                view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.listitem_device,viewGroup,false);
                viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
                /*viewHolder.deviceAddress = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.device_address);
                viewHolder.deviceName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.device_name);*/
                view.setTag(viewHolder);
            } else {
                viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
            }

            BluetoothDevice device = mLeDevices.get(i);
            final String deviceName = device.getName();
            if (deviceName != null && deviceName.length() > 0)
                viewHolder.deviceName.setText(deviceName);
            else
                viewHolder.deviceName.setText("R.string.unknown_device");
            viewHolder.deviceAddress.setText(device.getAddress());
            return view;
        }
    }
}
```

activity_b_t_scan.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".BTScanActivity">

    <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
    <TextView android:id="@android:id/empty"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FF0000"
        android:text="No data"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

listitem_device.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/device_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="24dp"/>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/device_address"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I have read the comment of an user from stackoverflow. Now I am doing Bluetooth advertisement in the other mobile. Still then I am not able to discover the mobile phone through Bluetooth. The code I am using is as below.

CODE:
MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    static final String LOG_TAG = "MySuperClass";
    static final int REQUEST = 112;
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            String[] PERMISSIONS = {Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION};
            if (!hasPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS)) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) this, PERMISSIONS, REQUEST );
                //imagePath.setText("SDK>23,has no permission");
                Toast.makeText(this, "SDK greater than 23,has no permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                example2();

            } else {
                //do here
                //imagePath.setText("SDK>23,has no permission");
                Toast.makeText(this, "SDK lesser than 23,has no permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                example2();

            }
        } else {
            //do here
            //imagePath.setText("SDK<23");
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "The app was  allowed to read your store.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                example2();
            }

        }
    }
    private static boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String... permissions) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && context != null && permissions != null) {
            for (String permission : permissions) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    //do here
                    Toast.makeText(this, "The app was  allowed to read your store.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "The app was not allowed to read your store.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    void example2() {
        BluetoothAdapter adapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        BluetoothLeAdvertiser advertiser =
                BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getBluetoothLeAdvertiser();

        // Check if all features are supported
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            if (!adapter.isLe2MPhySupported()) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "2M PHY not supported!");
                return;
            }


            if (!adapter.isLeExtendedAdvertisingSupported()) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "LE Extended Advertising not supported!");
                return;
            }



            int maxDataLength = adapter.getLeMaximumAdvertisingDataLength();


        AdvertisingSetParameters.Builder parameters = null;

            parameters = (new AdvertisingSetParameters.Builder())
                    .setLegacyMode(false)
                    .setInterval(AdvertisingSetParameters.INTERVAL_HIGH)
                    .setTxPowerLevel(AdvertisingSetParameters.TX_POWER_MEDIUM)
                    .setPrimaryPhy(BluetoothDevice.PHY_LE_1M)
                    .setSecondaryPhy(BluetoothDevice.PHY_LE_2M);


        AdvertiseData data = (new AdvertiseData.Builder()).addServiceData(new
                        ParcelUuid(UUID.randomUUID()),
                "You should be able to fit large amounts of data up to maxDataLength. This goes up to 1650 bytes. For legacy advertising this would not work".getBytes()).build();
        final AdvertisingSet[] currentAdvertisingSet = new AdvertisingSet[1];
        AdvertisingSetCallback callback = null;

            callback = new AdvertisingSetCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onAdvertisingSetStarted(AdvertisingSet advertisingSet, int txPower, int status) {
                    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onAdvertisingSetStarted(): txPower:" + txPower + " , status: "
                            + status);
                    currentAdvertisingSet[0] = advertisingSet;
                }

                @Override
                public void onAdvertisingSetStopped(AdvertisingSet advertisingSet) {
                    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onAdvertisingSetStopped():");
                }
            };



            advertiser.startAdvertisingSet(parameters.build(), data, null, null, null, callback);


        // After the set starts, you can modify the data and parameters of currentAdvertisingSet.
       
            currentAdvertisingSet[0].setAdvertisingData((new
                    AdvertiseData.Builder()).addServiceData(new ParcelUuid(UUID.randomUUID()),
                    "Without disabling the advertiser first, you can set the data, if new data is less than 251 bytes long.".getBytes()).build());


        // Wait for onAdvertisingDataSet callback...

        // Can also stop and restart the advertising
        currentAdvertisingSet[0].enableAdvertising(false, 0, 0);
        // Wait for onAdvertisingEnabled callback...
        currentAdvertisingSet[0].enableAdvertising(true, 0, 0);
        // Wait for onAdvertisingEnabled callback...

        // Or modify the parameters - i.e. lower the tx power
        currentAdvertisingSet[0].enableAdvertising(false, 0, 0);
        // Wait for onAdvertisingEnabled callback...
        currentAdvertisingSet[0].setAdvertisingParameters(parameters.setTxPowerLevel
                (AdvertisingSetParameters.TX_POWER_LOW).build());
        // Wait for onAdvertisingParametersUpdated callback...
        currentAdvertisingSet[0].enableAdvertising(true, 0, 0);
        // Wait for onAdvertisingEnabled callback...

        // When done with the advertising:

            advertiser.stopAdvertisingSet(callback);
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you started BLE advertising on the second phone?

Comment: How to do that? I do not know about that. I just clicked on the Bluetooth icon. Can you help or give me a link regarding that?

Comment: I downloaded another piece of code from github. That is also not finding BLE devices.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=Android+ble+advertising

Comment: I did Bluetooth advertising. But still unable to discover. Check my updated code in the original post. What am I doing wrong?